# onCreate method is called again whenever I shifts from one tab to other

Tags: android, google-maps, android-tabhost

I am making an android app in which I am using TabHost. in the first tab (named "MAP VIEW") I am displaying map in it and second tab is for listview (named "DETAILS VIEW"). My problem is when I switch from my MAP VIEW tab to DETAILS VIEW tab and then return back to MAP VIEW tab onCreate method is called again and map starts loading again. All I want is, When I returned back to MAP VIEW tab it will save its behaviour that I left it for first time.

Here is my Java class which displaying Tabs.

```
private static final String MAP_TAB_TAG = "MAP VIEW";
    private static final String DETAILS_TAB_TAG = "DETAILS VIEW";
    private TabHost tHost;
    private ListView mList;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        tHost = getTabHost();

        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent(Second.this, MapsView.class);

        tHost.addTab(tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("MAP VIEW").setContent(intent));

        intent= new Intent(Second.this, DetailsView.class);

    tHost.addTab(tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("DETAILS VIEW").setContent(intent));
```

Here is my MAP VIEW Java code (In this class onCreate is called every time when I get back to this class)

```
public class MapsView extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener,
        OnMapLongClickListener, OnCameraChangeListener,
        OnInfoWindowClickListener , OnMarkerClickListener, LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String LAT = "lat";
    private static final String LONG = "lng";
    Geocoder coder;
    String address;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;

    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
              .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
              .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
              .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps_view);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationClient.connect();

        System.out.println("Oncreate");

        coder = new Geocoder(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (mLocationClient != null) {
              mLocationClient.disconnect();
            }
    }

    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
          mLocationClient = new LocationClient(
              getApplicationContext(),
              this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
              this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
      }

    public void showMyLocation(View view) {
        if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
          String msg = "Location = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }

     @Override
      public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

         Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            REQUEST,
            this);  // LocationListener
      }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();  
        }
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,
        // 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

        try {
            List<Address> list = coder.getFromLocation(point.latitude,
                    point.longitude, 1);
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                mMap.clear();
                address = "";
                if (list.get(0).getAddressLine(0) != null) {

                    address += list.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " ";
                }

                if (list.get(0).getAddressLine(1) != null) {

                    address += list.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";
                }

                if (list.get(0).getAddressLine(2) != null) {

                    address += list.get(0).getAddressLine(2) + " ";

                }



            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(point)
                        .title(address)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.traffic_pin)));

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String lat = "" + marker.getPosition().latitude;
        String lng = "" + marker.getPosition().longitude;

        startActivity(new Intent(MapsView.this, Tab.class).putExtra(LAT, lat)
                .putExtra(LONG, lng).putExtra("title", marker.getTitle()).putExtra("address", address));
    }
```

Here is LogCat showing results

```
06-20 17:04:42.823: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4371): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-20 17:04:51.098: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1155K, 26% free 28199K/38023K, paused 15ms+7ms, total 73ms
06-20 17:04:51.098: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 48ms
06-20 17:04:51.143: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 329K, 25% free 28887K/38023K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
06-20 17:04:51.263: D/SensorManager(4371): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)b)a-,(
06-20 17:04:52.933: D/GestureDetector(4371): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-20 17:04:53.098: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1100K, 22% free 29771K/38023K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 51ms
06-20 17:04:57.068: D/Result(4371): s
06-20 17:04:57.073: D/Result:(4371): s
06-20 17:04:57.263: D/SensorManager(4371): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)b)a-,(
06-20 17:04:57.263: D/Sensors(4371): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
06-20 17:04:57.263: I/Sensors(4371): sendDelay --- 200000000
06-20 17:04:57.263: D/SensorManager(4371): JNI - sendDelay
06-20 17:04:57.263: I/SensorManager(4371): Set normal delay = true
06-20 17:04:57.408: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1963K, 22% free 29734K/38023K, paused 13ms+15ms, total 82ms
06-20 17:04:57.523: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4371): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
06-20 17:04:57.523: I/dalvikvm(4371): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
06-20 17:04:57.583: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4371): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-20 17:05:02.578: D/GestureDetector(4371): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-20 17:05:02.698: D/AbsListView(4371): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-20 17:05:02.708: D/ProgressBar(4371): setProgress = 0
06-20 17:05:02.708: D/ProgressBar(4371): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
06-20 17:05:02.708: D/ProgressBar(4371): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
06-20 17:05:02.818: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:02.818: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:04.203: D/response(4371): {"data":[{"id":"1","device_id":"123","lat":"33.6605","lng":"73.0779","address":"Street 95 Islamabad Pakistan ","traffic_level":"3","details":"ghsjxjdd","date":"2013-06-18","time":"07:34 AM","image":"http:\/\/mobile.s3technology.net\/traffic\/images\/123\/c48f2201f748550f9442b326c9a00d60.jpg"},{"id":"2","device_id":"123","lat":"33.6606","lng":"73.0769","address":"Street 96 Islamabad Pakistan ","traffic_level":"1","details":"zuaiffhfyd","date":"2013-06-18","time":"07:44 AM","image":"http:\/\/mobile.s3technology.net\/traffic\/images\/123\/5be821ec69ea233c11be8c7448646613.jpg"},{"id":"3","device_id":"123","lat":"33.6602","lng":"73.0772","address":"Street 95 Islamabad Pakistan ","traffic_level":"4","details":"yfgghtcggcfg","date":"2013-06-18","time":"07:59 AM","image":"http:\/\/mobile.s3technology.net\/traffic\/images\/123\/fb801c3f5872049029bd9e54598d4dcb.jpg"},{"id":"4","device_id":"123","lat":"33.6621","lng":"73.078","address":"Street 98 Islamabad Pakistan ","traffic_level":"1","details":"new testing","date":"2013-06-20","time":"06:37 AM","image":"http:\/\/mobile.s3technology.net\/traffic\/images\/123\/e091977ec224a60e6eb160d74799d591.jpg"},{"id":"5","device_id":"123","lat":"33.6686","lng":"73.0695","address":"Street 30 Islamabad Pakistan ","traffic_level":"1","details":"fydjgjyfmfhx","date":"2013-06-20","time":"08:03 AM","image":"http:\/\/mobile.s3technology.net\/traffic\/images\/123\/5a909c814bf9e89352073a3d76138b4d.jpg"},{"id":"6","device_id":"123","lat":"33.6707","lng":"73.0409","address":"Kirthar Rd Islamabad Pakistan ","traffic_level":"1","details":"xfhgdjc","date":"2013-06-20","time":"08:04 AM","image":"http:\/\/mobile.s3technology.net\/traffic\/images\/123\/d5e52d50ec1d78a664b6d4aeb039b080.jpg"}]}
06-20 17:05:04.453: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:04.453: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:06.038: D/GestureDetector(4371): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 21 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-20 17:05:09.058: D/GestureDetector(4371): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 10 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-20 17:05:09.788: D/GestureDetector(4371): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-20 17:05:10.003: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3357K, 26% free 28235K/38023K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
06-20 17:05:10.003: I/dalvikvm-heap(4371): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.033MB for 1836252-byte allocation
06-20 17:05:10.053: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 105K, 25% free 29923K/39879K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
06-20 17:05:10.053: D/AbsListView(4371): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
06-20 17:05:10.053: I/MotionRecognitionManager(4371):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,)b/fa*(
06-20 17:05:10.103: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 26% free 29836K/39879K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
06-20 17:05:10.108: I/dalvikvm-heap(4371): Grow heap (frag case) to 32.958MB for 3264524-byte allocation
06-20 17:05:10.158: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 24% free 33016K/43079K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 51ms
06-20 17:05:10.333: W/SurfaceView(4371): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
06-20 17:05:10.368: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:10.368: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:11.578: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:11.578: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:12.813: D/GestureDetector(4371): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-20 17:05:12.853: D/AbsListView(4371): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-20 17:05:12.863: I/System.out(4371): Oncreate
06-20 17:05:12.878: W/SurfaceView(4371): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
06-20 17:05:12.953: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:12.953: E/SpannableStringBuilder(4371): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-20 17:05:13.028: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3371K, 27% free 31689K/43079K, paused 2ms+10ms, total 37ms
06-20 17:05:13.028: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
06-20 17:05:13.028: D/AbsListView(4371): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
06-20 17:05:13.033: I/MotionRecognitionManager(4371):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,))e+aa8
06-20 17:05:13.168: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5680K, 35% free 28002K/43079K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 47ms
06-20 17:05:13.168: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
06-20 17:05:14.493: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1931K, 35% free 28011K/43079K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 55ms
06-20 17:05:14.703: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1408K, 34% free 28651K/43079K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 39ms
06-20 17:05:14.703: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
06-20 17:05:14.703: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
06-20 17:05:14.888: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1972K, 34% free 28705K/43079K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 47ms
06-20 17:05:14.888: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
06-20 17:05:15.153: D/dalvikvm(4371): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1944K, 34% free 28777K/43079K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 46ms
06-20 17:05:15.153: D/dalvikvm(4371): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
06-20 17:05:42.838: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4371): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
06-20 17:05:42.843: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4371): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Any Help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: `TabActivity` -- what I presume you are using since your tab contents are `Intents` -- has been deprecated for well over two years. Please consider moving to a modern tab solution: `FragmentTabHost`, `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, action bar tabs, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare But in past i have been using `TabActivity` and this kind of behaviour doesn't happened!! why my activity is recreated every time i shift from tabs and back to it?? **deprecated** doesn't mean you can't use it

Comment: "deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it" -- correct. Deprecated means that Google thinks that there are better solutions. In this case, IMHO, they certainly are correct. IMHO, activities-in-tabs has always been a poor solution, more of a hack than something well-designed. Nowadays, there are much better solutions, with backports working all the way back to API Level 7, and some further back than that. You do not have to use them, but don't complain when people point them out to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK thats fine and honestly im not complaining about your *pointing*, im just curious to know that in past i have used `TabHost` with  `Tab Activity` more than 10 times, and the activity never gets recreated i.e `onCreate()` just get called one time!! kindly tell me this why this certain behaviour is happening? why `onCreate()` getting called every time when i switch back to tab?

Comment: "kindly tell me this why this certain behaviour is happening?" -- I have been telling people *not* to use activities-in-tabs for years. Hence, I have no recent experience with them. That being said, if it is `onCreate()` of your *fragment* that is being called each time, perhaps you should be thinking about when and how you are causing that fragment to be created. After all, `TabActivity` knows nothing about fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Last I have found the solution of the problem :-) I was doing logical mistake in my TabHost class have a look at code

```
private static final String MAP_TAB_TAG = "MAP VIEW";
    private static final String DETAILS_TAB_TAG = "DETAILS VIEW";
    private TabHost tHost;
    private ListView mList;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        tHost = getTabHost();

        Intent intent;


 intent = new Intent(Second.this, MapsView.class);

        tHost.addTab(tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("MAP VIEW").setContent(intent));

        intent= new Intent(Second.this, DetailsView.class);

    tHost.addTab(tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("DETAILS VIEW").setContent(intent));
```

in the "DETAILS VIEW" part I gave the `tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG)` but `MAP_TAB_TAG` was static variable used for the `MAP VIEW` tab and `DETAILS_TAB_TAG` is used for `DETAILS VIEW` tab. So, my logical mistake was I was giving

`tHost.addTab(tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("MAP VIEW").setContent(intent));
 tHost.addTab(tHost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("DETAILS VIEW").setContent(intent));`

as you can see `tHost.newTabSpec(MaP_TAG_TAG)`is used for both tabs and that was my mistake and now I have solved this problem thanks for the comments and reply any way